# Is there a cleaner way to group and summarize multiple variables multiple ways in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, survey

This is my first post.  Apologies if I botch something.

I have employee opinion survey data that has 5 point likert scale data along with department (and other demographic data).  I would like to get a % unfavorable (a 1 or 2 survey response), % neutral (a survey response == 3), and % favorable (a 4 or 5 response).  I would also like to have those %s for each department. I have the result I am looking for with the sample data below but I actually have 30+ variables.  I'm hoping there is a cleaner way to do this!

Here is my sample data:

```
survey <- data.frame(department = c('hr', 'hr', 'tech', 'tech', 'tech', 'hr', 'hr', 'tech', 'tech', 'tech'),
                  pride = c(1, 5, 2, 3, NA, 5, 5, 2, 3, NA),
                  satisfaction = c(5, 2, 3, NA, 5, 5, 2, 3, NA, 3),
                  leadership = c(5, 2, 3, NA, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 3))
```

I am able to pretty easily get % favorable using this:

```
items <- c('pride', 'satisfaction', 'leadership')
output <- survey %>% 
  group_by(department) %>% 
  mutate_at(items, recode, `1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 1, `5` = 1) %>%
  summarize_at(items, mean, na.rm = T) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(engagement = mean(c(pride,satisfaction,leadership), na.rm = T)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(department))
```

It starts to become messy once I attempt to do all 3 calculations (%unfav, %neutral, and %fav).  Is there a better way than this (which does give me the desired output - again it's not very scalable considering I actually have 30+ variables):

```
items_fav <- c('pride_fav', 'satisfaction_fav', 'leadership_fav')
items_neutral <- c('pride_neut', 'satisfaction_neut', 'leadership_neut')
items_unfav <- c('pride_unfav', 'satisfaction_unfav', 'leadership_unfav')
all_items <- (c('pride_fav', 'satisfaction_fav', 'leadership_fav','pride_neut', 'satisfaction_neut', 'leadership_neut','pride_unfav', 'satisfaction_unfav', 'leadership_unfav'))
output_3parts <- survey %>%
  mutate(pride_fav = pride, 
         satisfaction_fav = satisfaction,
         leadership_fav = leadership, 
         pride_neut = pride, 
         satisfaction_neut = satisfaction,
         leadership_neut = leadership,
         pride_unfav = pride, 
         satisfaction_unfav = satisfaction,
         leadership_unfav = leadership) %>%
  mutate_at(items_fav, recode, `1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 1, `5` = 1) %>%
  mutate_at(items_neutral, recode, `1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 1, `4` = 0, `5` = 0) %>%
  mutate_at(items_unfav, recode, `1` = 1, `2` = 1, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, `5` = 0) %>%
  group_by(department) %>%
  summarize_at(all_items, mean , na.rm = T)
```

Output would look something like this:

Row 1: department   pride_fav   satisfaction_fav    leadership_fav  pride_neut  satisfaction_neut   leadership_neut pride_unfav satisfaction_unfav  leadership_unfav

Row 2: hr   0.75    0.5 0.25    0   0   0   0.25    0.5 0.75

Row 3: tech 0   0.25    0.4 0.5 0.75    0.4 0.5 0   0.2

Thanks!

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Comment: I updated the post to include output.  I'm not sure the best way to add a table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this might do what you're looking for.

```
library(tidyverse)
)
survey %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -department, names_to = "quality", values_to = "ranking") %>%
  group_by(department, quality) %>%
  summarise(mean_score = mean(ranking, na.rm = T)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = quality, values_from = mean_score)
```